# Make running python script more responsive to ctrl c?

Tags: python

We are running a very large framework of python scripts for test automation and I do really miss the opportunity to kill a running python script with ctrl + c in some situations on Windows.

When the script might be doing some socket communications with long time-outs the only options sometimes is to kill the DOS window.. Is there any options I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using blocking calls with long timeouts, use event-driven networking. This will allow you never to have long periods of time doing uninterruptable operations.

Comment: Did you mean "uninterruptable"? Don't want to put words in your mouth. :)

Comment: I have inherited the framework (15-20k lines of code) so in time I might solve the issues with time outs.. were more looking for some magic key combination :)

Comment: And we are using the Pyro libs and I don't want to mess to much with that.

Comment: @Paul, Yet again, I am caught by mindless spellcheck accepting. `:)`

Comment: @StefanE, I know of no magic for this, and I'm certain if there is any it's not portable.

Answer (score 0):

Look for instances of:

```
try:
    some code
except:
    # catches all exceptions, including ^C
```

Change to:

```
try:
    some code
except Exception:
    # catches most exceptions, but not KeyboardInterrupt or SystemExit
```

Comment: It's fairly certain that the issue is blocking calls not allowing the interpreter to raise KeyboardInterrupt, rather than catching and ignoring it.

Comment: Note that both of these instances should be used absurdly sparingly, at least if they don't come with a bare `raise`.